# Oracle Query help for LIKE statement

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have an Oracle query that return my VIP count but i need it to return 3 different columns with ALL things from es.ticket_id tallied then only things containing VIP in Price_scale then things NOT  containing VIP in price_scale

```
SELECT
    e.event_code,
    e.event_date,
    e.description,
    COUNT(es.ticket_id) AS attendance
FROM
    event e
    LEFT JOIN event_seat es ON e.event_id = es.event_id
    Left JOIN mydb.price_scale ON es.price_scale_id = mydb.price_scale.price_scale_id
WHERE
    e.description LIKE '%Test%'
    AND e.description NOT LIKE '%Gif%'
    AND e.event_date BETWEEN '01-JAN-20%' AND '31-JAN-23%'
    AND e.event_status_code <> 'HLD'
    AND e.venue_id = 100
    AND dixier_read_only.price_scale.description LIKE 'VIP%'
GROUP BY
    e.event_code,
    e.event_date,
    e.description
ORDER BY
    e.event_code
```

so es.ticket_id is the item that needs to tally in to the columns of Attendance, VIP and Regular

any help would be greatly appreciated

The above code only returns what i can assume is the VIP

Comment: If `e.event_date` is the `date` datatype, you need to work with it as date, not varchar2. So use `e.event_date BETWEEN date'2020-01-01' and date'2023-01-31'` instead

Comment: i can do that but that wont help break the data out in to the 3 seperate counts ?

Comment: or could the select portion go something like SELECT
    e.event_code,
    e.event_date,
    e.description,
    COUNT(es.ticket_id) AS attendance,
    SUM(es.ticket_id CASE WHEN .price_scale.description = 'VIP%' then 1 else 0 end) AS VIP